# bootstrap hover moving all the links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, hover

I'm playing around with bootstrap and I have some problem. I created a navigation with few links and I want bottom border to appear when I hover the link. I made it and now, when I hover, links are "moving" to the top, even though I didn't give them any margin or padding... 
Here is JSFiddle with the example, you need to resize the window of outcome to be able to see entire menu.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/zhzmz6fa/
```

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">O nas</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Opis</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Archiwum</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
.navbar {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: orangered;

}

.navbar-toggler {
    border: none;
}

.nav-item {
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    transition: border-bottom .5s;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borders count extra in the calculation of width. So if you have

```
width: 50px;
border-right: 1px solid black;
```

The element will be 51px wide.

This is also what happens with your code. The solution would be to always give it a border, but have it transparent.

```
.nav-link {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: I decided to use that solution, it's working. Thank you.

Comment: You're Welcome. Could you then please close the question? (Mark an answer as the solution)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `border` is a pseudoelement.

Style it as you need, set it's `opacity` to 0. On `:hover`, or `:active` change the `opacity` to 1.

```css
.navbar {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
}

.nav-item {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-link {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: black;
}

.nav-link:hover:after,
.nav-link:active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x100" class="navbar-brand"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">O nas</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Opis</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Archiwum</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```